# how to access input text box in code with razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

i making worksystem with razor page in asp

I want to add a value to the input text when a button is pressed.

this is input box

[]

click button

⑤

input box add five

[5]

how to access input text box in code

this is AddWork.cshtml input text

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
        InputWork: <input type="text" asp-for="boradIds" />
        <select asp-for="inputIds" asp-items="Model.seletcIdList">
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>
```

this is call AddWork cs func

```
<form method="post">
   <input asp-page-handler="AddItem" asp-route-resoruceId=@item.board_id
      class="btn" type="submit" value="AddWork" />
 </form>
```

this is cs.

```
  [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public string boradIds { get; set; }
 public IActionResult OnPostAddItem(int bid)
 {
            //if (bid == 0)
            //    return Page();
            boradIds =boradIds +bid.ToString();

            return  RedirectToPage();

}
```

i don't know how to access input text value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get boradIds in OnPostAddItem,you need to put `<input type="text" asp-for="boradIds" />` into the form which will call `OnPostAddItem`.

```
<form method="post">
   InputWork: <input type="text" asp-for="boradIds" />
        <select asp-for="inputIds" asp-items="Model.seletcIdList">
        </select>
   <input asp-page-handler="AddItem" asp-route-resoruceId=@item.board_id
      class="btn" type="submit" value="AddWork" />
 </form>
```

So that when you click AddWork button,it will pass boradIds and resoruceId to  handler,if you want to get resoruceId  in handler,you need to use `int resoruceId`.

Comment: Can I edit the input text directly through this code?

Comment: You mean if you change the boradIds,boradIds in .cs file will change or not?If so,it will change.

Comment: What I think the meaning is that when the corresponding 5 button is pressed, the value 5 that I specified should be added to the input text of the screen the user sees

Comment: Do you have any js to do this?

Comment: As a result of my search, I confirmed that it is possible with js.
But now, I imported the js itself because I made it using the razor page I made.

Comment: Can you share your js?

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/2125013.aspx?Text+Change+Event+for+an+Input+Text+